# .htaccess, чпу, get параметр

Tags: .htaccess, get, чпу

Что нужно прописать в htaccess, что бы превратить ссылку

```
http://domain/profile?id=1
```

в

```
http://domain/profile/id/1
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте этот код:

```
RewriteRule ^profile\?id=([0-9]+)$ profile/id/$1 [L]
```

В регулярном выражении используется группа с захватом, в которую попадают все цифры, а затем они подставляются в целевой URL с помощью конструкции `$1`.

Также не забудьте в начале файла .htaccess прописать:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

и проверить, что mod_rewrite есть в вашей версии apache.

Comment: Internal Server Error, не работает =/

Comment: @sabotage911 также не забудьте в начале файла .htaccess прописать "RewriteEngine On" и проверить, что mod_rewrite есть в вашей версии apache. а что именно пишет при выводе ошибки и какое поведение (идет перенаправление или ничего не происходит)? проверьте логи apache, что именно там выдает сервер.

Comment: htaccess в принципе работает у меня, реврайт включен. Но при этом коде пишет ошибку

Comment: попробуйте тогда для теста сделать RewriteRule ^profile\?id=111$ test [L] где в id указываете один из уже существующих id профилей, а в браузере вам надо будет вбить ваш.сайт/test или как вариант без экранирования ^profile?id=111$ test [L] (все равно будет валидно для теста).

Comment: Query-часть URL лучше вытягивать через `RewriteCond`. Например `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)$` затем уже использовать его `RewriteRule ^profile$ profile/id/%1`